# Ipo module in Blender 2.74 using python

Tags: python

I need to update a 2.49 blender code to 2.74 but I can't find in Blender 2.74 a module named `Ipo`. Someone can help me? Below, part of my code in 2.49 version.

```
  obj = Object.Get('obj'+str(visNames.index(ni)))    

  ipo = Ipo.New('Object','obj'+str(visNames.index(ni))+'.ipo')
  obj.setIpo(ipo)

  curveTime = ipo.addCurve('Time')
  curveTime.setInterpolation('Linear')   

  curveLocX = ipo.addCurve('LocX')
  curveLocX.setInterpolation('Linear')   

  curveLocY = ipo.addCurve('LocY')
  curveLocY.setInterpolation('Linear')   

  curveLocZ = ipo.addCurve('LocZ')
  curveLocZ.setInterpolation('Linear')
```

Answer (score 4):

From 2.50 Ipo's have been replaced with [Actions](https://www.blender.org/manual/animation/actions.html). While you can create an action with `bpy.ops.action.new()` you can also just add a keyframe to a property and the action will be created for you. Instead of Ipo curves we now use [f-curves](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.FCurve.html).

Starting with getting an object by name

```
obj = bpy.data.objects['Cube']
```

You can then use [keyframe_insert](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.bpy_struct.html#bpy.types.bpy_struct.keyframe_insert) to key all 3 axes of the objects location with

```
obj.keyframe_insert('location')
```

To key just one axis you can specify an index (X=0 Y=1 Z=2)

```
obj.keyframe_insert('location', index=0)
```

You could add multiple keyframes from a list

```
x = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
xframes = [0, 10, 20]
for i in range(len(x)):
    obj.location.x = x[i]
    obj.keyframe_insert('location', index=0, frame=xframes[i])
```

For the interpolation, each [keyframe](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Keyframe.html) has it's own interpolation setting. A simple loop can set each keyframe to use the same interpolation.

```
objCurves = obj.animation_data.action.fcurves
for curve in objCurves:
    # here you can also test curve.array_index to find
    # the curve of a specific axis
    # array_index matches the index used in keyframe_insert
    if curve.data_path == 'location':
        for k in curve.keyframe_points:
            k.interpolation = 'LINEAR'
```

From blender v2.76 you can use `objCurves.find()` to get the specific curve that you want.

```
objCurves = obj.animation_data.action.fcurves
for i in [0,1,2]:
    curve = objCurves.find('location', index=i)
    for k in curve.keyframe_points:
        k.interpolation = 'LINEAR'
```

Comment: Thanks @sambler, this explanation was very useful for me. But, there is an error in `curve = objCurves.find('location', index=i)` that appear the following message: _find() takes no keywords arguments_ . I didn't understand this. 

Finally, in 2.49 Ipo's version I have: `for i in range(len(x)):
                                                        curveLocX.addBezier((xtime[i],x[i]))`
Can I add Bezier using `keyframe_insert` after that linear interpolation that you showed for me?

Comment: My bad `fcurve.find()` was added in 2.76. You have one fcurve for each property, it contains a point for each keyframed value. You use multiple `keyframe_insert` with different frames to animate the value.